# find if there is a new object by createOrUpdateInRealm in realm

Tags: ios, objective-c, realm

Is there any way to find out that a new object is inserted by `createOrUpdateInRealm` method or not?

```
RLMRealm *realm = [RLMRealm defaultRealm];
SampleRealmObject *object     = [[SampleRealmObject alloc] init];
NSDictionary *item = @{@"id": @10, @"name": @"sampleName"};

for (RLMProperty *property in object.objectSchema.properties) {
    if([item objectForKey:property.name])
      {
            [object setValue:[item objectForKey:property.name] forKey:property.name];
       }
    }

// add or update the new object
[SampleRealmObject createOrUpdateInRealm:realm withValue:object];
```

Comment: Fetch the object using the `id`, if doesn't exist use the `add` or use the `update`.

Comment: @SachinVas I knew this approach, but I ask about something which this method may give us.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, `+createOrUpdateInRealm:withValue:` does not indicate whether the object was created or updated. If you need to know whether an object with the given primary key exists, you can use `+objectInRealm:forPrimaryKey:` to retrieve an existing object prior to using `+createOrUpdateInRealm:withValue:`.